# How to interpret Tobler’s First Law of Geography?

Tags: gis-principle, tobler, philosophy

Waldo Tobler's First Law of Geography is an axiom in GIS which states that "*everything is related to everything else, but near things are more related than distant things*" ([Tobler, 1969](https://www.jstor.org/stable/143141)). Another way of phrasing it would be to state that distance decay is the theoretical basis of spatial analysis for techniques such as kriging interpolation, spatial autocorrelation, and Huff Gravity Model to name a few. [To borrow a quote](https://gisgeography.com/tobler-first-law-of-geography/) which further expands on this assumption, "*as distance increases, the response variable becomes less predictable and is less related. But for closer things, the response is more predictable and has less variability*".

Where I have some tribulation comes from [a blog post](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/maps/l2_p2.html) by Dr. Robinson, who makes a subtle remark about Tobler's First Law stating that "*near things are more related, but that doesn’t mean they’re necessarily more similar (...) While it’s not necessarily true that stuff nearby is in fact similar, there are often aspects of similarity that can be observed and measured*".

Where I am having trouble is: **how do we distinguish the property of relatedness versus similitude by proximity between feature objects?** Is it that relatedness is a variable inherently dependent on geography between objects (say, sharing a common street address and number with my next-door neighbor, something incrementally subject to change with other nearby residents as distance increase); and that similitude is an independent variable from spatial distribution, with various degrees of correlation with distance (say, differences in spoken household languages between myself and my neighbors)?

In other words, **how do we define what are the "things" which are related to one another in Tobler's law?**

Comment: While this would be an interesting topic in [Chat], it seems more *discussion-oriented* than our Focused question/Best answer format here in the main site can handle.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131720/about-toblers-first-law

Answer (score 1):

I think that Tobler's law is more applicable to the natural world. To things related to the human perspective, the applicability depends on the subject of study. In the case of neighbors, there will be some similarities in the income between them, since houses next to each other tend to have similar characteristics. Maybe neighbors share the same religion, but to other aspects of the life, I think that Tobler's law will not help much.

Answer (score 1):

Think about temperature, rainfall or elevation: the closer two completely different objects are (a house, a bridge and a garden), the higher chances are that temperature, rainfall or elevation have similar values.

Even for human made and cultural this is somehow true, even if the effect is weaker: language use or names tend to be more similar inside a small area than a larger area.